# How do I multi-thread with private or public functions? C# 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

How do I multi-thread so that it will run private or public functions in the current class or different classes?

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: Then it looks like Google isn't being very friendly to me.

Comment: Can you clarify? what is "it"?

Comment: Do you want to run any class's functions on different thread OR run any class's private functions OR do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Action> tasks = new List<Action>();

tasks.Add(() => { ... do whatever });
tasks.Add(() => { ... do whatever });
tasks.Add(() => { ... do whatever });
tasks.Add(() => { ... do whatever });

System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(tasks.ToArray());
```

u can put this context in private or public method anywhere u like. and the execution context can also be both private and public.